# How do I merge long histories on two different repositories in git

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on github that I and a friend work concurrently on. We branched our local copies of the master on github and added a lot of features to our individual branches. But we only committed to our local copies (not the one on github). How do I manage the histories and commits such that both our commits are reflected on the github repository (without a flurry of merge conflicts)? Thanks.

Plus, how do I handle the conflicts and patches? Can someone provide a visual representation of the problem and how to solve it (so that I can better understand it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of merging your whole brunch of commits into the remote branch at one go which makes you lot of conflicts to solve, you can also merge your commits parts by parts.

```
`git merge <commit point a>`
```

solve some conflicts first

```
`git merge <commit point b>`
```

solve some conflicts first

```
`git merge <commit point c>`
```

solve the last part of conflicts

where a,b,c are the commits point in sha-1 and a < b < c

I think this would relieve your pain a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You're both going to have to

- **Merge** with remote (Github)
- **Push** to remote (Github)

The merge may result in conflicts. **There's no way around it**, thats just how Git works.
So my advice; for future projects, merge and push often to avoid conflicts, especially if it's likely you're both working on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, both worked on the `master` branch and all changes shall go to the `master` branch on Github. Do not use `pull` but `fetch` and `rebase` (described at [git ready](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html))

1. One of you both (say, 1) should `push` first to Github (preferably that one that has fewer changes)
2. The other (say, 2) `fetch`es from Github (do NOT pull): `git fetch github/master`
3. Then, 2 does a `git rebase github/master`
4. 2 resolves some conflicts
5. 2 does the `git push` to Github
6. 1 does the `git pull` from Github and will surely have **no conflicts**